# Audio gets held up in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, sound

I have this problem at random intervals where it seems the audio gets held up. For example, when I'm using Duolingo in Chrome, the sounds will suddenly not play. It goes silent for maybe about 15-30 seconds, and then suddenly all the sounds that didn't play are played at once. But the sounds never stop mid-play. It's as if they were in a line waiting to be played and the line was held up for a while, and then suddenly the line opened up again and all the sounds came rushing through at once.

But it also affects Rhythmox and the system sounds. When music hasn't been playing for a while in Rhythmbox, and I press the play button, it waits about 15 seconds, and then starts playing. And during that wait time, Rhythmbox is held up as well: it doesn't actually show the track seconds counting until the sound starts playing.

I've had Ubuntu 20.04 for quite a while, and this only started after I had to reinstall Ubuntu after accidentally uninstalling a major dependency (glib 2, to be exact). Does anyone know what's causing this, and how to fix it?

Comment: Try `sudo gedit /etc/pulse/daemon.conf`, and add `realtime-scheduling = no`. Then run `pulseaudio --kill` and `pulseaudio --start` then tell me whether that worked.

Comment: @Adnan Thanks! I'll try that as soon as I can. It's going to be a busy week for me, so it may take a while to get around to it, but I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: @Adnan I haven't tried your tip yet, but for the time being at least the problem has diminished. Thanks for the help, I'll let you know if I have the problem again (and after I try your solution).